# Set the intervals of x-axis using r

Tags: r, plot

I plot a distribution of visit time of a scenic spot from 0 to 23 hours in a day. And I want to **adjust the intervals of x-axis** letting all hours be displayed. How can I do that?

```
d = c(42,13,10,3,2,6,7,15,38,63,128,153,178,181,236,217,272,417,526,653,607,385,191,70)
plot(seq(0,23,by=1),c,type='b',col='red',main="Confucius Temple",xlab="Hours",ylab="Numbers of check-in")
```

[image]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use `axis`:

```
> axis(side=1, at=c(0:23))
```

That is, something like this:

```
plot(0:23, d, type='b', axes=FALSE)
axis(side=1, at=c(0:23))
axis(side=2, at=seq(0, 600, by=100))
box()
```