# Time in years(x axis) shows years in .5 interval - Time Series using R

Tags: r, time-series, data-visualization

> dsales1156ts<-ts(dsales1156,frequency=365,start=c(2011,6))  # This is my time series created with daily sales data when the first sale day is 6th January 2011.
>
> plot(dsales1156ts)

The graph is as attached below:

[image]

The problem is time in x-axis is taken at every .5 years interval. How do I change it to yearly? How do I get the points as 2011 , 2012 , 2013 instead of 2011.0 , 2011.5 , 2012.0 , 2012.5 , 2013 , 2013.5 ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what format your data is in, but you can use the axis() command to adjust options. Lots of other posts on stack about this, such as: [Set the intervals of x-axis using r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717545/set-the-intervals-of-x-axis-using-r)