# In R, how to set the breaks of x-axis?

Tags: r, plot

Say here is my code:

```
plot(data ylab="x", xlab="y", xlim=c(1, 13))
```

But the x-axis of the plot presented like this:
[image]

As you see, the x-axis presented from 2 to 12 by 2. However, I want it shown from 1 to 13 by 1 step, how can I realize that?

Comment: [Does this help?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717545/set-the-intervals-of-x-axis-using-r?rq=1) But the most straight-forward (and lesser known) way is to use the `lab = c(x, y, len)` argument (passed to par) which is the number of `x` and `y` ticks, and the `len`gth of the labels. So your code could look something like `plot(1:13, ylab="x", xlab="y", xlim=c(1, 13), lab = c(13,5,7))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this code: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Lemon-kickstart/axbreak.R

You have to source that file in order to use the function:

```
source('http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Lemon-kickstart/axbreak.R')
axis.break(axis=1,breakpos,bgcol="white",breakcol="black", style=c("slash","zigzag"),brw=0.02)
```

Adapt to your liking.

Comment: Thx for sharing this but I tried it and it said `Error in axis.break(axis = 1, breakpos, bgcol = "white", breakcol = "black",  : 
  object 'breakpos' not found`. Any advice?

Comment: Try setting breakpos to a value, like this: breakpos=17.0

Answer (score 14):

You've defined the limits for your axis; however, R is inserting the "default" values for it.

To alter them, you need to

1. "Override" the creation of the axis with `xaxt='n'`
2. Define a custom axis

So, let's get it done!

```
plot(data, ylab="x", xlab="y", xlim=c(1, 13), xaxt='n')
# Now, define a custom axis
axis(side = 1, at=1:13)
```

This will give you what you want.

---

From the documentation, [`axis()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/axis.html):

> **Description**
>
> Adds an axis to the current plot, allowing the specification of the side, position, labels, and other options.
>
> **Usage**
>
> `axis(side, at = NULL, labels = TRUE, tick = TRUE, line = NA,
>        pos = NA, outer = FALSE, font = NA, lty = "solid",
>        lwd = 1, lwd.ticks = lwd, col = NULL, col.ticks = NULL,
>        hadj = NA, padj = NA, ...)`

Some of the most used arguments are:

- `side` (integer) 1=below, 2=left, 3=above and 4=right.
- `at` (vector) position of the tick marks
- `labels` (vector) labels for the tick marks. The vector must be the same size of `at`. If ommited, the values of `at` will be used. `FALSE` hides any labels

---

Useful reference:

- [**The Quick-R tutorial** | Axes and text](http://statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html)